# QGIS 3 - Identify tool - programmatically accessing "Derived" info in Identify Results

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

Is it possible to access this info programmatically? I know that the  attributes portion of the identify results can be accessed, yet I can't seem to find examples pertaining to the "Derived" info - see the image below.

[image: Identify Results]

I realize that the derived info varies depending on the data type (ex. vector geometry type, Z/M enabled, raster, mesh etc.).

I'm interested in accessing info that isn't easily retrievable with other tools/methods - ex. the interpolated z value on a polygonZ layer.

Answer (score 4):

If you subclass `QgsMapToolIdentify`, you can do something like this (you can run this minimal example from an editor in the Python console to test):

```py
class selectTool(QgsMapToolIdentify):
    
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        QgsMapToolIdentify.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(self.active_changed)
        
    def active_changed(self, layer):
        if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer) and layer.isSpatial():
            self.layer = layer
            
    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        results = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), [self.layer], QgsMapToolIdentify.TopDownAll)
        for i in range(len(results)):
            print(results[i].mDerivedAttributes)
        
    def deactivate(self):
        self.iface.currentLayerChanged.disconnect(self.active_changed)
        
        
t = selectTool(iface)
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(t)
```

Example output (for a point layer):

```
{'(clicked coordinate X)': '699611.9', '(clicked coordinate Y)': '8623529.5', 'Feature ID': '683', 'X': '699611.2', 'Y': '8623530.3'}
```

And for a polygon layer:

```
{'(clicked coordinate X)': '699657.4', '(clicked coordinate Y)': '8623504.0', 'Area (Cartesian)': '10176.371 m²', 'Area (Ellipsoidal — EPSG:7019)': '10174.475 m²', 'Closest X': '699657.6', 'Closest Y': '8623504.5', 'Closest vertex X': '699668.8', 'Closest vertex Y': '8623500.6', 'Closest vertex number': '26', 'Feature ID': '9', 'Part number': '1', 'Parts': '1', 'Perimeter (Cartesian)': '528.540 m', 'Perimeter (Ellipsoidal — EPSG:7019)': '528.491 m', 'Vertices': '31'}
```

Comment: Great answer! This works exactly as expected for my polygonZ test layer. Specifically, the Interpolated Z value I'm interested in is included. I also quickly tested a 2DM mesh layer as well as a Float32 geotiff raster and they both worked as expected - code reported info matches that of the "Derived" info of the Identify tool.