# Fetching value from derived feature of shapefile in Python script

Tags: fields-attributes

I am trying to create one vector layer from another layer. For this, I need the values from the derived section of the feature as shown in the image.
Is there any way to fetch derived feature values like vertices, closest x, closest y, etc of any vector layer?

How do I fetch this data programmatically (python script) from QGIS?

I have tried the [identify](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422256/qgis-3-identify-tool-programmatically-accessing-derived-info-in-identify-r) code but I think it works for the raster layer only but I need it for a vector layer.

```
    Input:
        SMBR_geom, SMBR_area, SMBR_angle, SMBR_width, SMBR_height = geom.orientedMinimumBoundingBox()
print(f"SMBR_geom: {SMBR_geom}")
geod = Geod('+a=6378137 +f=0.0033528106647475126 +ellps=WGS84')
lons = [4.35139592233199579, 4.35171109758170971,4.35152993925688136, 4.35121476400716745,4.35139592233199579]
lats = [51.98570845113777494, 51.98583729839662482, 51.98628043254456799, 51.98615158528571811 ,51.98570845113777494]
poly_area, poly_perimeter = geod.polygon_area_perimeter(lons, lats)
print(f"polygon total area",poly_area)
    
    Output:
        
SMBR_geom: <QgsGeometry: Polygon ((4.35139592233199579 51.98570845113777494, 4.35171109758170971 51.98583729839662482, 4.35152993925688136 51.98628043254456799, 4.35121476400716745 51.98615158528571811, 4.35139592233199579 51.98570845113777494))>
    
polygon total area 1246.0209183692932 #this is a slightly correct output
```

How do I add dynamic x and y coordinates instead of static?so I try this.

```
 Input:
print(SMBR_geom.asPoint().x(), SMBR_geom.asPoint().y())) 

 Output:
Polygon geometry cannot be converted to a point. Only Point types are permitted
```

[image: Here I attached one image of one of my shapefile, I need a value of derived data]

Comment: What GIS software?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QGIS 3 - Identify tool - programmatically accessing "Derived" info in Identify Results](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422256/qgis-3-identify-tool-programmatically-accessing-derived-info-in-identify-r)